# Merging dataframes without duplicating rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a huge list of dataframes with the data structured in a way that makes merges tough. basically I read in a lot of nested directories worth of .xls files and so I have a list of dataframes where roughly every 5 or so should be combined horizontally into rows and each group of 5 should be combined vertically.

I'll try to give an example (group sizes reduced to 3 for simplicity).

```
df.list[1]:
id     Date     col1     col2
1      date1    <int>    <int>
2      date1    <int>    <int>
3      date1    <int>    <int>

df.list[2]:
id     Date     col3     col4
1      date1    <int>    <int>
2      date1    <int>    <int>
3      date1    <int>    <int>

df.list[3]:
id     Date     col5     col6
1      date1    <int>    <int>
2      date1    <int>    <int>
3      date1    <int>    <int>
```

then the next few are a different sample...

```
df.list[4]:
id     Date     col1     col2
1      date2    <int>    <int>
2      date2    <int>    <int>
3      date2    <int>    <int>

df.list[5]:
id     Date     col3     col4
1      date2    <int>    <int>
2      date2    <int>    <int>
3      date2    <int>    <int>

df.list[6]:
id     Date     col5     col6
1      date2    <int>    <int>
2      date2    <int>    <int>
3      date2    <int>    <int>
```

and this keeps going for a few thousand samples.
I've tried using bind_rows() from dplyr but that yields:

```
id     Date     col1     col2     col3     col4     col5     col6
1      date1    <int>    <int>      NA       NA       NA       NA
2      date1    <int>    <int>      NA       NA       NA       NA
3      date1    <int>    <int>      NA       NA       NA       NA
1      date1       NA       NA    <int>    <int>      NA       NA
2      date1       NA       NA    <int>    <int>      NA       NA
3      date1       NA       NA    <int>    <int>      NA       NA
1      date1       NA       NA      NA       NA     <int>    <int> 
2      date1       NA       NA      NA       NA     <int>    <int>
3      date1       NA       NA      NA       NA     <int>    <int>
1      date2    <int>    <int>      NA       NA       NA       NA
2      date2    <int>    <int>      NA       NA       NA       NA
3      date2    <int>    <int>      NA       NA       NA       NA
1      date2       NA       NA    <int>    <int>      NA       NA
2      date2       NA       NA    <int>    <int>      NA       NA
3      date2       NA       NA    <int>    <int>      NA       NA
1      date2       NA       NA      NA       NA     <int>    <int> 
2      date2       NA       NA      NA       NA     <int>    <int>
3      date2       NA       NA      NA       NA     <int>    <int>
```

This isn't the end of the world but the filesize is 5 times as large as it needs to be. Ideally the data would be structured like:

```
id     Date     col1     col2     col3     col4     col5     col6
1      date1    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
2      date1    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
3      date1    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
1      date2    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
2      date2    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
3      date2    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what I think you're looking for with tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

ex_list <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)

ex_list %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  gather(measure, value, col1:col4) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  spread(measure, value) %>% 
  arrange(date)


# A tibble: 6 x 6
     id       date  col1  col2  col3  col4
  <dbl>     <date> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 2017-01-01     1     4     7    10
2     2 2017-01-01     2     5     8    11
3     3 2017-01-01     3     6     9    12
4     1 2017-01-02    11    14    21    24
5     2 2017-01-02    12    15    22    25
6     3 2017-01-02    13    16    23    26
```

Data:

```
 df1 <- tibble(
      id = c(1,2,3),
      date = as.Date(c("2017-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-01-01")),
      col1 = c(1, 2, 3),
      col2 = c(4, 5, 6)
    )

    df2 <- tibble(
      id = c(1,2,3),
      date = as.Date(c("2017-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-01-01")),
      col3 = c(7, 8, 9),
      col4 = c(10, 11, 12)
    )

    df3 <- tibble(
      id = c(1,2,3),
      date = as.Date(c("2017-01-02", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-02")),
      col1 = c(11, 12, 13),
      col2 = c(14, 15, 16)
    )

    df4 <- tibble(
      id = c(1,2,3),
      date = as.Date(c("2017-01-02", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-02")),
      col3 = c(21, 22, 23),
      col4 = c(24, 25, 26)
    )
```

Comment: I think this works but it requires too much memory so unfortunately I can't use it.

Comment: This worked with a little tweaking. I also had to group by measure and then add a mutate id? Also I had to break the data into chunks. I'm not sure what a mutate id is though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a merge function first on the first group, and then you can rbind your data frame.
Using the data.table library, that is quite efficient:

```
Reduce(merge,df.list[1:3])
```

Will give the merged dataframe

```
   id  Date  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
1:  1 date1 <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
2:  2 date1 <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
3:  3 date1 <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
```

Then you need to make a list of them with lapply, and apply rbind to that list

```
do.call("rbind",lapply(list(c(1:3),c(4:6)),function(x){Reduce(merge,df.list[x])}))

   id  Date  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
1:  1 date1 <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
2:  2 date1 <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
3:  3 date1 <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
4:  1 date2 <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
5:  2 date2 <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
6:  3 date2 <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
```

the data:

```
library(data.table)
df.list <- list()

df.list[[1]] <- setDT(read.table(text = 
"  id     Date     col1     col2
  1      date1    <int>    <int>
  2      date1    <int>    <int>
  3      date1    <int>    <int>",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

df.list[[2]] <- setDT(read.table(text = 
"  id     Date     col3     col4
  1      date1    <int>    <int>
  2      date1    <int>    <int>
  3      date1    <int>    <int>",
 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

df.list[[3]] <- setDT(read.table(text = 
"  id     Date     col5     col6
 1      date1    <int>    <int>
 2      date1    <int>    <int>
 3      date1    <int>    <int>",
 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))


df.list[[4]] <- setDT(read.table(text = 
 "  id     Date     col1     col2
     1      date2    <int>    <int>
     2      date2    <int>    <int>
     3      date2    <int>    <int>",
     header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

df.list[[5]] <- setDT(read.table(text = 
  "  id     Date     col3     col4
  1      date2    <int>    <int>
  2      date2    <int>    <int>
  3      date2    <int>    <int>",
  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

df.list[[6]] <- setDT(read.table(text = 
    "  id     Date     col5     col6
    1      date2    <int>    <int>
    2      date2    <int>    <int>
    3      date2    <int>    <int>",
    header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

Comment: thanks for the input. Not all of the groups are the same size though. They range from 4 to 6 in size. I need to somehow bind them based on Date and id.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by the groups. If you mean the number of dataframe that you want to merge, you define it by the vector you pass to lapply (list(c(1:3),c(4:6)) in my answer with your example). If the number of the first group is 4 and the second 6, then list(c(1:4),c(5:11)) should do the job.
If I misunderstood what you mean, try an edit of your example giving a more realistic example

Comment: It is impossible for me to give a realistic example because there are thousands of dataframes. I explained as best as I could but there are far more than just two groups and going through and manually putting how many there  are is overly tedious. I found a working solution so far and am about to update.